# MongoDB aggregate project based on conditional logic of other field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate-functions

Let's say I have a Schema with a couple fields `foo` and `bar`;

I then want to retrieve all `Documents` using a `projection`. I want to retrieve all `foo`s and `bar`s with aliases and then "create" another field for my result based on some conditional logic of what `bar` is. If the condition is true, I simply want to tack on a leading '0' char to this new field, otherwise, I just want to set it to whatever `barAlias` is.

So, something like

```
const pipeline = [
        { $match: {} },
        {
            $project: {
                fooAlias: "$foo",
                barAlias: "$bar",
                newField: (if some condition with barAlias) ? '0' + barAlias : barAlias
            }
        }
    ];
const docs = await Collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

I know how to use `$cond` and `$concat`, but my issue here is that I'm trying to base my logic on the alias fields. Is this possible. Thanks!

Comment: Probably need to base it off of the actual name, not the alias.  The assumption being the aliases do not exist until after that stage in the pipeline.

Comment: Yeah, part of my question is if it's possible to get the alias value as the aggregate is being worked on. Your assumption makes sense

Comment: The values added during $project do not exist until the stage completes, so if you want to be based on the new value, you will need a second project stage.  As to the conditional part, did you try `$cond`?

Comment: You're saying I could use two `$project`s in the same pipeline? If so, what performance impacts would that have?